# Convert function in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-convert

I am using this query to display date and time. I have used the 113 in conversion function that gave me the date format with spaces and i replaced it with a /, now i just want to take out the / that separates date from time.

```
 SELECT [ID]
      ,REPLACE(convert(varchar, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime, 113), ' ','/') as RecievingDate
      FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
      where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo
```

It gives this result:

```
09/Jun/2014/10:04:07:000
```

That's what i want, it works perfectly but problem is that i want to remove '/' after 2014, like `09/Jun/2014 10:04:07:000`

but in other places '/' this should remain same but it should not appear after 2014.

how ?

Comment: Do you really have to do this db-side?  Application languages usually have better facilities for this...

Answer (score 1):

Dirty but works:

```
SELECT 
      LEFT(REPLACE(convert(varchar, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime, 113), ' ','/'), 11) + ' ' +
      RIGHT(REPLACE(convert(varchar, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime, 113), ' ','/'), 12)
      as RecievingDate
FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
      where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQLServer 2012 or better you can use the new function `FORMAT`

```
SELECT [ID]
     , FORMAT(ReceivedDateTime, 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss:ms') as RecievingDate
FROM   [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
WHERE  Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom 
  AND  Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo
```

In the `FORMAT` function `hh` is for 12-hour format, `HH` for 24-hour format, you can add `tt` to get `AM` or `PM`, to see the difference try

```
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME()(), 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss:ms tt') _12
     , FORMAT(SYSDATETIME()(), 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:ms') _24
```

Also you should not change the data stored (that can be in a index) to match a parameter, if should be the other way around

```
SELECT [ID]
     , FORMAT(ReceivedDateTime, 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss:ms') as RecievingDate
FROM   [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
WHERE  ReceivedDateTime >= Cast(@DateFrom AS DateTime2)
  AND  ReceivedDateTime <= DateAdd(dd, 1, DateAdd(ms, -1, Cast(@DateTo as DateTime2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `replace` function

```
SELECT [ID], 
       convert(varchar, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime, 113) as RecievingDate
  FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
 where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime) >= @DateFrom 
   AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo
```

Comment: it would remove '/' from all places which i don't want, i just want to remove 1 '/' just before 2014

Comment: You mean just after? I undestand now, the 113 of convertion function give you the date format with spaces and you replace it with a `/` you just want to take out the `/` that separates date from time. I think you can update your question to explain it better.

Comment: like this

09/Jun/2014 10:04:07:000

Comment: You can accept the answer from @robertw it will give you what you want. :)

Comment: ok done but how to convert time to 12 hours format insteat of 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '/') + ' '
       +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) as [DD/Mon/YYYY HH:MM:SS]
```

In your query as:

```
SELECT [ID]
,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime , 106), ' ', '/') + ' '
+  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime , 108) as RecievingDate
FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom 
AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo
```

[Edit]
For 12 hr format write as :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '/') + ' '
+ substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 109),13,
Len (CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 109))) as [DD/Mon/YYYY HH:MI:SS:MMMAM (or PM)]
```

and modify your query as:

```
SELECT [ID]
,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime , 106), ' ', '/') 
+ ' '
+  substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime , 109),13,
Len (CONVERT(VARCHAR, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime , 109))) as RecievingDate
FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom 
AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select [ID]
     , replace(left(convert(varchar,getdate(),113),11),' ','/')+
       right(convert(varchar,getdate(),113),13) 
       as RecievingDate
FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
       where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom 
       AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo
```

you only need to use the replace function on the 1st part, not on the 2nd part like in robertw's answer.